# Jest finishing async test before done()

Tags: asynchronous, testing, jestjs

I'm writing an async test in Jest and having trouble. I'm pretty sure the test is finishing and passing before the async call returns anything in spite of everything I've tried. I know the function works because it logs out the correct response after the test suite has finished. Here is the test code:

```
describe('updateUser', () => {
  test('should update a user', (done) => {

    updateUser(user).then(({err, res}) => {
      console.log('updated user:', err, res); // this show up after the test is done
      expect(err).toBeFalsy();
      expect(res).toBeTruthy();
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

console output:

```
 updateUser
   ✓ should update a user (68ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        6.058s
Ran all test suites.
 console.log server/db/crud_Users/crud_user.test.js:38
   updated user: null { homeLocations: [],
     meetingPlaces: [],
     hostedEvents: [],
     attendingEvents: [],
     flags: [],
     tokens: [],
     _id: 5b2147495995cb45f9c4f079,
     name: 'test',
     email: '83277963493533480000@test.com',
     password: 'testtest',
     ageRange: '1',
     gender: 'Female',
     accountCreatedAt: null,
     __v: 0 }
```

Expected behavior: the test suite waits for the console.log statement and the assertions to run before finishing.

Actual behavior: it doesn't.

I also tried making the test callback an async function and awaiting the `updateUser` call, but nothing changed; I tried tacking the `done()` callback on in a second `.then` block as well, with no results.

Comment: Jest captures stdout and doesn't render it until the end. See [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/8208). Your test is correct otherwise and this is normal behavior.

Answer (score 2):

It's just about how Jest output things in async tests. I have just checked but don't see how to proof that.

If you remove `done();` call you will get test failed because of timeout exceeded.
If you change your expectation to be invalid you will also get your test failed. 
So it works fine. For sure.

Also since `updateUser` returns Promise you don't need to run `done()`. Just return Promise so test would be slightly lighter:

```
test('should update a user', () => {
  return updateUser(user).then(({err, res}) => {
    expect(err).toBeFalsy();
    expect(res).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```